# Error in D-BUS session in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, dbus

Hi I get the following error upon starting the `xfce4-panel`

```
Failed to connect to the D-BUS session bus: Failed to connect to socket
```

However Dbus is running as i checked it in `HTOP`
I get the error in multiple applications such as terminal emulator. This happened after an unplanned power off due to a power error in my home. I think it is a config file corruption.
How can I fix this